# Can anyone explain the following C syntax?

Tags: c, syntax, avr

I came across with a library for [FAT file system](http://www.sf.net/projects/efsl/). It is a library for embedded systems. In the example code I found some interesting lines which I do not understand.

**Here is the problematic line:**:

```
sd_protocol.spiHwInit=(void *)atmega_spi_init;
```

where `sd_protocol` is a struct `SdSpiProtocol sd_protocol;`

**Here is the type definition**:

```
struct _SdSpiProtocol
{
    void *spiHwInterface;
    euint8 (*spiHwInit)(void* spiHwInterface);
    euint8 (*spiSendByte)(void* spiHwInterface,euint8 data);
};
typedef struct _SdSpiProtocol SdSpiProtocol;
```

**and `atmega_spi_init` is the following function**:

```
euint8 atmega_spi_init(atmegaSpiInterface *iface)
{
    euint8 i;

    /* Unselect card */
    PORTB |= iface->pinSelect;

    /* Set as master, clock and chip select output */
    DDR_SPI = (1<<DD_MOSI) | (1<<DD_SCK) | 1;

    /* Enable SPI, master, set clock rate to fck/2 */
    SPCR = (1<<SPE) | (1<<MSTR); /* fsck / 4 */
    SPSR = 1; /* fsck / 2 */

    /* Send 10 spi commands with card not selected */
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        atmega_spi_send(iface,0xff);

    /* Select card */
    PORTB &= ~(iface->pinSelect);

    return(0);
}
```

`sd_protocol.spiHwInit=(void *)atmega_spi_init;` this is not a function call, then what it is?

and I do not understand what this line supposed to do either, in the type definition:

`euint8 (*spiHwInit)(void* spiHwInterface);`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `(void*)bar` is a cast to a void pointer (a pointer with no other type information). The other line is a declaration of a pointer to a function.

Comment: It's a typecast. The second one is a function pointer.

Comment: [Function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a function call but a function pointer:

[How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

And your line is cast from a specific function pointer to a void pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct _SdSpiProtocol
{
  void *spiHwInterface;
  euint8 (*spiHwInit)(void* spiHwInterface);
  euint8 (*spiSendByte)(void* spiHwInterface,euint8 data);
};
typedef struct _SdSpiProtocol SdSpiProtocol;
```

The `spiHwInit` member is a pointer to function taking a `void *` parameter and returning `euint8`.

```
euint8 atmega_spi_init(atmegaSpiInterface *iface);

sd_protocol.spiHwInit=(void *)atmega_spi_init;
```

This line is an assignment. It converts `atmega_spi_init` (which is a function) to a `(void *)` and assigns it to `.spiHwInit`.

However, this is wrong for more than one reason. Firstly, a *function pointer* can not, by any C standard, be converted to a `void *` with any well-defined result. An *object pointer* can be converted to `void *` and back to the same type with well-defined results, but not a function pointer.

Secondly, (assuming that `atmegaSpiInterface` is a structure and not a `void *`), the code converts one type of function pointer to `void *` and then to a *different* type of function pointer. If the function is called through a function pointer *of the wrong type*, the behaviour is undefined.

The correct way to do this is to define the function `atmega_spi_init()` to have the *same type* as the `.spiHwInterface` member, i.e. with a `void *` parameter. The assignment can then be made without a cast, and the function call through the `.spiHwInterface` is perfectly well-defined. You just have convert the `iface` parameter to the correct type before using it inside the function.

Of course, there may other standards (such as POSIX) or compiler extension that allow all of these conversions with well-defined results.

Comment: As a matter of fact it is not my code, but thanks for this additional information.

Comment: As a note, POSIX defines those conversions.

Comment: @mafso: Good to know! Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Not a normative one unfortunately, @NisseEngström, but [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html) is an example (under "Application Usage") stating explicitly that `void *`-to`function pointer conversion are well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

This line `euint8 (*spiHwInit)(void* spiHwInterface);` declares `spiHwInit` as a pointer to function. The "problematic" line sets that pointer to a concrete function `sd_protocol.spiHwInit`.